Could not determine recommended JdbcType" error with Hibernate @Embeddable annotation
Issue:
I'm encountering an error while working with Hibernate annotations, specifically when using the @Embeddable annotation. The error message I'm receiving is:
Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.jack.secondTrail.Certificate'
Context:
I'm utilizing Hibernate annotations, particularly @Embeddable, in my Java project. The @Embeddable annotation is used to indicate that a class is to be embedded into another entity. In my case, I have a class named Certificate that I intend to embed into another entity.
The whole code:
EmbedTable.java file
package com.jack.secondTrail;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class EmbedTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //configuration     
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure();
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        
        //1st student object        
        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.setId(1254);
        student1.setName("Anuv Jain");
        student1.setAddress("Mumbai");
        
        //1st certificate obj for student 1
        Certificate certificate = new Certificate();
        certificate.setCourse("Java Development");
        certificate.setCourse("5 months");
        student1.setCerti(certificate);
        
        
        //2nd student object 
        Student student2 = new Student();
        student2.setId(1546);
        student2.setName("Nakul Dhull");
        student2.setAddress("Gurgaon");
        
        //2nd certificate object for student 2
        Certificate certificate2 = new Certificate();
        certificate2.setCourse("API Design");
        certificate2.setDuration("4 months");
        student2.setCerti(certificate2);
        
        
        //open session to changes
        Session se = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = se.beginTransaction(); //for saving..
        
        se.save(student1);
        se.save(student2);
        
        tx.commit();
        
        se.close();
        factory.close();
        
        
    }
}

Certificate.java file:
package com.jack.secondTrail;

public class Certificate {
    
    private String course;
    private String duration;
    
    
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    
    
    public Certificate(String course, String duration) {
        super();
        this.course = course;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public Certificate() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
}

Student Class:
package com.jack.secondTrail;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    private Certificate certi;
    
    
    public Student(int id, String name, String address, Certificate certi) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.certi = certi;
    }

    public Student() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public Certificate getCerti() {
        return certi;
    }


    public void setCerti(Certificate certi) {
        this.certi = certi;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.id+" : "+ this.name+" : "+ this.address;
    }

}


You need to add the @Embeddable anotation to your class, which is Embedded, not your Main Class.
Means: Remove @Embeddable from your EmbedTable class and add it to the class Certificate .
package com.jack.secondTrail;

@Embeddable
public class Certificate {
    
    private String course;
    private String duration;
    
    
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    
    
    public Certificate(String course, String duration) {
        super();
        this.course = course;
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public Certificate() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
}

Then add @Embedded to your Student class:
package com.jack.secondTrail;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    @Embedded
    private Certificate certi;
    
    
    public Student(int id, String name, String address, Certificate certi) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.certi = certi;
    }

    public Student() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public Certificate getCerti() {
        return certi;
    }


    public void setCerti(Certificate certi) {
        this.certi = certi;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.id+" : "+ this.name+" : "+ this.address;
    }

}

See also here: https://openjpa.apache.org/embeddable-samples.html

See here.
In your case, your Certificate is your embeddable, and needs to bee embedded in the Student class.
You need to remove the @Embeddable annotation from your EmbedTable.java file and add the @Embeddable and @Embedded annotations in your Student and Certificate classes.
In your Certificate class:
@Embeddable
public class Certificate {
    ...
}

In your Student Class:
@Entity
public class Student {
    
    ...

    @Embedded
    private Certificate certi;
    
    ...

}

